# HTML, hiding form and show form while username and password match

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am trying to do, form1 is hidden right now, if that username and password correct as in my code, than show form1 in same tab/window, so if username and password correct than next page says Hello!  logged in, Is there any way that, i can do that?? I know i can create another html, if username and password correct than show that html, I can do that, I want to send html by email to if i send two html it won't work so, is there any way that i can do everything in one html, if username and password correct than show that hidden form.. Please help me!! Thanks!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0042)http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/RHwLW/show/ -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title> - jsFiddle demo by DrydenLong</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./- jsFiddle demo by DrydenLong_files/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="./- jsFiddle demo by DrydenLong_files/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./- jsFiddle demo by DrydenLong_files/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./- jsFiddle demo by DrydenLong_files/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    #hello, #sorry {
    display: none;
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_button").click(function(){
        var userid = $("#user").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        if (userid == 'username' && pass == 'password') {
            $("#login").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#hello").fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $("#login").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#sorry").fadeIn();
        });
    }});});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="login">
    <form name="login">Username
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="user">Password
        <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="pass">
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="my_button">
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="hello">Hello! You are logged in.</div>
<div id="sorry">Sorry you have entered the wrong username or password</div>






</body></html>
```

Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: I might be a little off-track here as I'm not 100% sure of what your asking when it comes to emailing your HTML, but you could look into using some kind of modal set-up or possibly an iframe... Does the "Hello" page need to be in a different tab?

Comment: I am saying is, After log in it take you next screen so, is there anyway that, I can do everything in one html file, instead of create another html?? and noo, hello page should be in same page

Comment: You can't directly use a single HTML file for multiple pages, but you could use some server-side script to reference a single HTML file, and display specific content. To be honest though, that seems a bit unnecessary. Depending on your security needs, you could use JS/Jquery to scroll through multiple hidden divs upon logging in... I'll post an answer soon with an example and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this uses Jquery/JqueryUI to hide/show content based off of the values of your form fields. Depending on the values, the appropriate `div` is faded into view:

HTML

```
<div id="login">
    <form name="login">Username
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="user" />Password
        <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="pass" />
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="my_button"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="hello">Hello! You are logged in.</div>
    <div id="sorry">Sorry you have entered the wrong username or password</div>
```

CSS

```
#hello, #sorry {
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my_button").click(function () {
        var userid = $("#user").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        if (userid == 'username' && pass == 'password') {
            $("#login").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $("#hello").fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $("#login").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $("#sorry").fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now, there is a major problem with this code if you want your site to have secure content. Anybody can view the source code of your page and see the content that is being hidden, defeating the purpose of using a password to gain access. You will have to figure out a way to improve upon that if you want better security. If that's the case, you may want to look into a server-side scripting language such as PHP to address the security issue.

If security isn't a huge deal and the username/password is more for displaying the *experience* of what's in the `div` rather than the content, then this should do just fine.

Here is a fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/RHwLW/

Comment: Man Thank you so much for your help!! Really appreciate!!:) I will ask you for more questions!! haha...:)

Comment: I can write everything in one html file right?? do i need to merge the code????? I am really sorry, i am begining for html!! thanks!!

Comment: all i need to merge one by one??

Comment: I don't understand the question... What are you merging?